# Run psexec by asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, execute, psexec

I run psexec in visual studio but I can not in IIS. I search some days all given solutions is old and there is not usable these days.
my OS is Windows 10 and it is my code:

```
 string psFileName = Server.MapPath(".") + @"\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe";
            string computerName = "computerName";
            string userName = "DOMAIN\\userName";
            string password = "password";
            string exePath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
            string paramters = "\"https://www.google.com\"";
```

```
  private void RunRemote(string psFileName, string computerName, string userName, string password, string exePath, string paramters)
        {
            //  string path = Application.StartupPath+ @"\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
            try
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(psFileName);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

                psi.Domain = "ITCPIDC-CENTER";
                psi.UserName = "gholizadeh.al";

                SecureString theSecureString = new NetworkCredential("", password).SecurePassword;
                psi.Password = theSecureString;

                psi.Arguments = $"\\\\{computerName} -d -u {userName} -p {password} \"{exePath}\" {paramters}";

               


                process.StartInfo = psi;
                process.Start();


                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Label1.Text = output;
                string errormessage = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Label1.Text = errormessage;
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }


        }
```

I expected to run firefox by psexec in asp.net web form but just run in visual studio running

Comment: If you read a little bit more on Windows session isolation, you will see why your expectation is unrealistic, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Besides, a web app is too easy to be hacked, so never attempt to run even crazier bits like psexec in it. It might look good enough if you just play and learn, but real world applications shouldn't be developed that way.

Comment: Thanks  it is very useful. I had read some pages that pointed the mentioned matter but I tried to find a solution to solve the problem by granting access to the account.

Comment: If you want to try it, I found some ideas could share with you. You could put the domain, username and password directly into the PsExec command arguments. Hope it works for you.